# Building an installer, to install dlls to the gac, with MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, windows-installer, gac, msbuild-task

I have a dll project which I need to install into the GAC, on our Production machines. 
(I wish I didn't have to use the GAC but SSIS insists)

gacutil.exe is not available on the target machines and using "Enterprise.Services" from PowerShell does not work (I don't know why)

My understanding is I should created a msi installer project.

However after installing the Setup and Deploy Extension to Visual Studio (2015 soon to be 2017), I discovered those projects cannot be built by our Build Server because it uses MSBuild, and MSBuild can't build vdproj project files.

**What is the correct way, using a CI build pipeline (MSBuild), to create build artifacts, which can install dlls to the GAC, of a Production Environment?**

*Note: there are several partial answers on SO, but I could not find any, which were up to date/answer my whole question. Please keep that in mind when answering.*

Answer (score 0):

You need to break this down into several user stories.   You aren't finding partial answers, you are finding actual answers for specific questions.  What you ask is more like an epic.

In general I would create an MSI using Windows Installer XML.  WiX/MSI can install files to the GAC without using GACUTIL.  If you use the WiX Visual Studio extension "Votive"  you can create a .SLN  / .WIXPROJ / .WXS  that can be built using MSBuild.  You can then put this into a source control system such as Git/TFVC/Subversion and use a build system such as VSTS V.Next Build, XAML Build, Concourse, Jenkins  to automation the pipeline to build the MSI.